# VGA Graphics card is not guaranteed to operate normally

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

Recently I updated the BIOS for my GigaByte Motherboard using Q-Flash Utility .

The update was successful but under the MB Intelligent Tweaker menu in BIOS , there's a warning says **VGA Graphics card is not guaranteed to operate normally**

and when I logged on into windows , the screen resolution was changed to `1024 * 768`
and it was `1440 * 960` , now `1440 * 960` is not available under resoultion list .

I reinstalled the Nvidia driver but nothing changed.

My motherboard version

http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3454#bios

Answer (score 2):

Updating your BIOS shouldn't mess up your card like that. Go to device manager and find your graphics card. Then uninstall it. Reboot your computer, check device manager that your card is recognized. If that doesn't work, then open up Q-Flash and flash your BIOS back to the other version that you were on.